Selenium - found button element ("download") which is in two states: 1. aria-hidden="true" 2. The one I want to interact with but can't
Backdrop:
I'm trying to test out my overall program to download an Excel file that will change on a weekly basis, then analyze the differences. I'm hosting the Excel file in Google Drive (which I'm hoping isn't introducing a one-of-a-kind problem).
Problem:
I'm currently stuck on the download part of my Python code. Google Drive has two Elements I believe that allow for the download. (1) A download icon which I've correctly found (how do I know: I used JavaScript in the Chrome Console and it executes the download flawlessly). (2) The 3-dots menu has a submenu item called "Download" which I have not been able to target (find). The Inspect Element doesn't find the Download action in the submenu; this has been the harder route to try and solve so I'm focusing on route (1).
What I've implemented:
Logging
Arbitrary timeouts
Expected Conditions
By
WebDriverWait
ActionChains
I've checked frames too. It doesn't appear to be inside one but I could be wrong.
Here's my code:
import os
import time # Insert a pause before performing a click
from selenium import webdriver
import logging  # Import logging for logging setup
import configparser  # Import configparser for configuration file handling
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException  # Include TimeoutException
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='logging.log', level=logging.INFO)

# Load configuration file for using credentials
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('credentials.ini')

username = config['credentials']['username']
password = config['credentials']['password']

# Download directory path
download_dir = '/path/to/directory'  # My real code has the correct path.

# Set up Chrome driver
def setup_driver():
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {'download.default_directory': download_dir}
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")  # Additional undetectable options
    

    try:
        driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
        return driver
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Failed to initialize undetected_chromedriver: {e}")
        raise

def main():
    driver = setup_driver()
    try:
        # Navigate to the website
        driver.get('https://drive.google.com/drive/home')
        logging.info("Navigated to login page successfully.")
        
        try:
            # Enter Username

            .....continued.

        # Wait for the page to load after login
        time.sleep(5)  # Add a small delay before trying to find the download button.

        # Log the current page source for debugging
        # logging.info(driver.page_source)  # Log the page source for debugging

        # Try to find the download button
        try:
            download_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Download']"))
            )

            # Debugging: Log the button's attributes and state
            logging.info(f"Download button found: {download_button.get_attribute('outerHTML')}")
            logging.info(f"Button displayed: {download_button.is_displayed()}")
            logging.info(f"Button enabled: {download_button.is_enabled()}")

            # Check if the button is interactable before clicking
            if download_button.is_displayed() and download_button.is_enabled():
                # Use ActionChains to click the button
                actions = ActionChains(driver)
                actions.move_to_element(download_button).click().perform()  # Move to the button and click
                logging.info("Clicked the download button using ActionChains.")
                # Adding a wait after clicking the button
                time.sleep(10)  # Wait for a few seconds to see if the download initiates

            else:
                logging.error("Download button is not interactable.")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            logging.error("Download button not found.")
        except TimeoutException:
            logging.error("Timed out waiting for the download button to become clickable.")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Error clicking download button: {e}", exc_info=True)


    finally:
        # Close the browser
        driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I was expecting the Download to execute. Just like the JavaScript code in the console but executed using Python equivalent block of Try Except statements.
Here's the JavaScript that works:
document.querySelector('button[aria-label="Download"]').click();
What I believe is happening is there are two states of the Download icon appearing when going route 1. It seems there are two elements associated with the "Download" functionality. Here’s a breakdown of what I found.

First Element:
This element has aria-hidden="true" and aria-disabled="true", and its style is set to display: none;. I believe this means it's currently not visible and not interactive.

div class="h-sb-Ic h-R-d h-R-d-db a-c-d a-s-Ba-d-Mr-Be-nAm6yf" role="button" aria-hidden="true" aria-disabled="true" data-tooltip="Download" aria-label="Download" ... style="user-select: none; display: none;"

Second Element:
This element is a button with aria-label="Download" and appears to be the one I should interact with. However, it also seems to have some complex interactions set up through JavaScript.

button class="pYTkkf-c-d ... aria-label="Download" ...
The issue likely stems from the fact that the first element is blocking interaction with the second one, or the second element may not be in a state that allows it to be clicked (e.g., it's not visible or enabled). Trying to force explicit wait time has not worked. I've waited 10 seconds up to 60 seconds.

Do you selecting a file before locating the download button ?
Since the route (1) download button appears(displayed) only if you select the file.

You do not need to select the row (box) in order for the download button to appear nor do you need to select the row (box) in order for the download to execute.
